# Merge two UIImages

Tags: image, ios4, uiimage

I have imageA (taken from the users iPhone camera) and imageB, an image with a silly boarder (for eg) with plenty of transparent alpha space.

What I would like to to do is to merge these two images, laying imageB over imageA, and then saving them as imageC for other work.

Is there a way to do this?

Cheers

I've got this so far

```
-(void)merge
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGPoint thumbPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    UIImage *imageA = imageView.image;
    [imageA drawAtPoint:thumbPoint];

    UIImage* starred = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageB.png"];

    CGPoint starredPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [starred drawAtPoint:starredPoint];

    UIImage *imageC = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    imageView.image = imageC;
}
```

I can't see/dont know what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Love the simplicity on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code looks correct (though I would recommend converting it to use a created [CGBitmapContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) for thread-safety), but is `imageB` supposed to be a JPEG? JPEGs don't support transparency, so, in order for the blending to work, it should really be a PNG.

Comment: was mean to be a png, no difference though.

Comment: ah it was the location of the code that did it - turns out imageView.image was nil.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for retina support you should use: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0); // 0 means let iOS deal with scale for you`