# How can the overlay and preview be taken in the same photo?

Tags: ios4

Overlaying an image on the preview is understood to be possible and straightforward.

But what is the correct way to save the overlay together with the captured image ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the captured image from the camera and then build a new UIImage with your overlay. These SO post should provide what you need to make the new image.

[Create a UIImage from two other UIImages on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679245/create-a-uiimage-from-two-other-uiimages-on-the-iphone)

[blend two uiimages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309757/blend-two-uiimages)

[Merge two UIImages.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374188/merge-two-uiimages)